# Unix: Changing the mask of an extended ACL

Tags: unix, permissions, acl

I am writing a script which touches a file and afterwards modifies the access control list the way that one particular user (say  peter) shall have full permissions to that file. Therefore I must add peter and a mask as well, if there was no one before.
For example

```
    # file: newfile
    # owner: hans
    # group: hansgroup
    user::rwx
    user:peter:rwxc
    group::r-x
    mask::rwx
    other::r--
```

The mask must give full permissions as well, otherwise peter's entry would be masked.
So, what if there is already a mask entry because there are other special user or group entries (which could come from a default ACL for the directory) - can I just change the mask to rwx in order to enable full permissions for my new peter entry? I am sure I would - in some cases - change the effective permissions of some other special entries if I extend the mask?

If no, don't I need to worry about the extension of the mask? Isn't that a problem?

If yes, I see a dilemma in it. What could I do?

I am familiar with this documentation of acls: http://www.suse.de/~agruen/acl/linux-acls/linux-acls-final.pdf

Comment: are ACLs standardized across all OS vendors? Maybe you should edit your posting to include links for the ACL documentation you're familiar with. Good luck.

Comment: I am referring this to publication: http://www.suse.de/~agruen/acl/linux-acls/linux-acls-final.pdf
I know ACLs have not been included in the POSIX standard, this paper, however, tries to explain the functionality which is implemented in a few linux distributions.